# Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory in angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm

I'm using Angular 7.2. When I enter `ng serve`, I'm facing the following issue:

> **FATAL ERROR:** Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

What does that mean? How do I fix that?

The full error message is:

```
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
1: 0x8f9d10 node::Abort() [ng serve --aot --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check --live-reload --progress]
2: 0x8f9d5c  [ng serve --aot --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check --live-reload --progress]
3: 0xaffd0e v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [ng serve --aot --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check --live-reload --progress]
4: 0xafff44 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [ng serve --aot --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check --live-reload --progress]
5: 0xef4152  [ng serve --aot --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check --live-reload --progress]
6: 0xef4258 v8::internal::Heap::CheckIneffectiveMarkCompact(unsigned long, double) [ng serve --aot --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check --live-reload --progress]
7: 0xf00332 v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [ng serve --aot --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check --live-reload --progress]
8: 0xf00c64 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [ng serve --aot --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check --live-reload --progress]
9: 0xf038d1 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFail(int, v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [ng serve --aot --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check --live-reload --progress]
10: 0xeccd54 v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationSpace) [ng serve --aot --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check --live-reload --progress]
11: 0x116cede v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInNewSpace(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [ng serve --aot --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check --live-reload --progress]
12: 0x19f62a4dbe1d
Aborted (core dumped) 
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 134
npm ERR! colo-ui@2.0.11 start: `ng serve --aot --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check --live-reload --progress `
npm ERR! Exit status 134
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the colo-ui@2.0.11 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-01-29T07_09_21_844Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

try running the build with this

```
node --max_old_space_size=8048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve
```

or other way is to add this to the package.json

```
"build-serve": "node --max_old_space_size=8048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve"
```

where 8048 is the max heap size.

Comment: let the size be 8192 instead of 8048

Answer (score 11):

**Issue:** While building(compiling), memory exceeds allocated memory for compilation.

**Fix:** Increase allocation memory. `8192` is the size used in the below script. You can vary this according to your need.

Try to run commands like this:

**Serving**:

```
node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve
```

**Building**:

```
node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod
```

**Custom script:**

Your script command(as mentioned in comment):

```
ng serve --aot --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check --live-reload --progress
```

Modify to:

```
node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve --aot --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check --live-reload --progress
```

Comment: we are using "npm run start" to run the project and the script tag contain script as     

"start": "ng serve --aot --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check --live-reload --progress ",

Comment: Updated answer :)

Comment: Instead of increasing allocated memory for compilation, shouldn't we try to figure out why so much memory is needed during compilation and fix that?

Comment: Definitely. This solution is required only if the memory consumption can't be decreased further.

Answer (score 7):

If you're on older version of NodeJS, then upgrading NodeJS to v12 helps solving this problem.

NodeJS v12 has different heap management strategy, see more info [here](https://foundation.nodejs.org/announcements/2019/04/24/node-js-foundation-and-js-foundation-merge-to-form-openjs-foundation-2).

Comment: For me this issue literally didn't show up UNTIL exactly the point when I upgraded NodeJS to v12 (from v10). Which was very confusing.

Answer (score -2):

Try updating node.js package from https://nodejs.org/en/download/